# How do I fully refresh an ASP.NET page so that Page_Load is run again?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, browser

I have an ASP.NET page where an iframe src is being dynamically set:

```
<iframe id="specialframe" src="<%= IframeSrc %>"></iframe>
```

And the codebehind:

```
internal string IframeSrc { get; set; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IframeSrc = SpecialService.GetNewUrl();
}
```

`SpecialService` is a third-party service that, when called, returns a one-time use URL that looks something like:

```
http://www.specialservice.com/oneTimeUseId=fh8396123lkjufgh49
```

For security purposes, this ID can only be used once before expiring. However, this leads to a problem.

The first time I display the page in a browser, it loads the iframe correctly. However, if I hit **refresh**, I will receive an error message in the iframe because it's trying to use the same one-time use ID. It works properly if I **Ctrl+F5** refresh to force a cache clear, but I can't tell my users to do that every time.

My question is, is it possible to force the browser to never use the cache and **always** request a fresh copy from the server?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set expiration and caching one your page correctly so browser always will have to request page from the server.

This question maybe a good start http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y18he7cw.aspx.

You need cacheability to none (and maybe to set expiration in the past, maybe SetMaxAge too):

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-30));
```